# The Functional Equation $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$ where $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(2)=2$, and $f(m) > fn)$ if $m>n$.

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics, functional-equations

The following is exercise 3.3 from Terence Tao's "Solving Mathematical Problems." Emphasis added.

> Suppose $f$ is a function on the positive integers which takes ***real*** values with the following properties:
>
> (a) $f(2)=2$
>
> (b) $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$ for all positive integers $m$, $n$.
>
> (c) $f(m)>f(n)$ if $m>n$.
>
> Find $f(1983)$. (Hint: First try to prove that $f(3)=3$ by comparing $f(2^n)$ with $f(3^m)$ for various integers $m$, $n$.) For an additional challenge, replace $f(2)=2$ with $f(n)=n$ for at least one integer $n \geq 2$.

Tao demonstrates in the book that $f(n)=n$ is the only function with these properties when $f$ takes integer values, and the proof relies heavily on this restriction. If $f$ takes *real* values, then his proof does not work, although it's implied in the hint that the solution is the same. Despite the hint, I've been unable to prove even that $f(3)=3$, much less get to the "challenge" part of the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $n \in \mathbf N$, then 
$$ 3^n = 2^{n \log_2 3} $$ 
hence, as $f(2^k) = 2^k$ for $k \in \mathbf N$ by multiplicativity,
$$ 2^{\lfloor n \log_2 3\rfloor} \le f(3^n) = f(3)^n \le 2^{\lceil n \log_2 3\rceil} 
$$
hence
$$ 2^{n^{-1}\lfloor n \log_2 3\rfloor} \le f(3)\le 2^{n^{-1}\lceil n \log_2 3\rceil} 
$$
For $n \to \infty$, we get 
$$ 2^{\log_2 3} \le f(3) \le 2^{\log_2 3} $$
Hence $f(3) = 3$. Along the same line of thought, we get $f(n) = n$ for all $n \in \mathbf N$.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking of homing in on $f(3)$ through successive approximations but didn't get that far.

Comment: can following can be solved with the same concept. http://imgur.com/AtFhkM4

Comment: The above gives you that $f(k) = k$ for all $k$, yes. Then the sum should be easy.